# ngrok free static domain (unknown flag --domain)

Tags: ngrok

I am on ngrok's free tier, v3.0.3, and trying to start a tunnel using ngrok http --domain=xx-xx-xx.ngrok-free.app 80

But I get the following error: "unknown flag --domain".

Would anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: You're using some old version of ngrok, try updating it. See https://ngrok.com/blog-post/new-ngrok-domains clic changes section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PM from ngrok here. As mentioned by [@Elias Soares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429323/elias-soares), [upgrade to the latest version of ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) which at the time of this post is 3.3.5. If you can't upgrade (which you should), try using `--hostname` instead of `--domain`.